# highcharts datetime point at fixed distance

Tags: datetime, highcharts, fixed

sorry if my question has already been aswered.

Here is an Highcharts example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d58vwagf/4/)

As you can see the xaxys is in scale... is there a way to have all the columns centered, and with the same distance between each other, regardless the datetime?

```
    var categoriesGrafico = [1417388400000, 1418511600000, 1418598000000, 1419894000000 ];

var seriesGrafico = [
  {
    "name": "605392037434",

    "data": [
      {
        "name": "D140088572",
        "x": 1417388400000,
        "y": 55.21
      },
      {
        "name": "D140088572",
        "x": 1418511600000,
        "y": 55.21
      },
      {
        "name": "D140088572",
        "x": 1418598000000,
        "y": 55.21
      },
      {
        "name": "D140088572",
        "x": 1419894000000,
        "y": 55.21
      }      
    ],
    "_colorIndex": 0
  }
  ];
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },title: {
                text: 'title'
            },plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    minPointLength: 2
                }
            },xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                title: {
                    text: 'date'
                },
                tickPositions:  categoriesGrafico,
                labels:{
                    rotation: -90,
                    formatter:function(){
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y',this.value);
                    }
                },
                reversed: true,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%d/%m/%Y',
                }
            },yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'value'
                },
                min: 0
            },
        series: seriesGrafico
    });
});
```

A sort of category or linear graph...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Answer below is correct - in Highstock `ordinal` option is what you need, but you need license for it. Anyway, workaround when using categories: http://jsfiddle.net/d58vwagf/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HighStock's `ordinal` value within the `xAxis`. However that might mean that you have to get additional licenses if you have not paid for HighStock and only paid for HighCharts - [refer here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#highstock-features-in-highcharts)

The ordinal parameter in the [HighStock API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) and [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/ordinal-false/)

Comment: ok thank you, I think i will convert it to a category graph :(